# Prove that $D$ is dense in $M$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $M$ be a complete metric space. If $M=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n$, where each $E_n$ is closed. Show that
$$D=\cup_{n=1}^\infty \text{int}(E_n)$$
is dense in $M$.

We have $M\setminus D=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \text{bdry}(E_n)$. Since each $E_n$ is closed, so $\text{bdry}(E_n)$ is nowhere dense set. But union of n.w.d. sets is not necessarily n.w.d., otherwise we can conclude that $D$ is dense in $X$.

Any hint?

Comment: Do you know the Baire category theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Baire category theorem says tells us that in a complete metric space a countable union of nowhere dense sets is co-dense (i.e. has dense complement).

A space $X$ is called [Baire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space) if $\bigcap_n G_n$ is dense in $X$ for every sequence of open and dense subspaces $G_n$ of $X$. Complete metric spaces are Baire spaces (that is one of the formulations of the Baire category theorem), and the previous statement follows by complementation and de Morgan, and the realisation that $O$ is open and dense iff $X\setminus O$ is closed and nowhere dense.

$X\setminus \partial E_n$ is open and dense for all $n$. So Baire says that $\bigcap_n (X\setminus \partial E_n) = X\setminus \bigcup_n  \partial E_n$ is dense, which is exactly your set $D = \bigcup_n \operatorname{int}(E_n)$.

Comment: So you are claiming that $M\D$ is closed and n.w.d. I am not getting this point, how it is n.w.d. ?

Comment: @Empty no, I’m only claiming it’s complement is dense. Nowhere do I say what you’re claiming.

Comment: @Empty every complement of $\partial E_n$ is open and dense. So the intersection of their complements is dense.